# Apache HttpComponents times out after multiple requests

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x, resource-leak

I'm using HttpClient 4.3 with a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and two threads which each connect to a REST API. Both are permanently sending requests. It works well for some minutes, but then, the requests begin to timeout. While browsing, even Chrome cannot establish connections to websites. This is my code for sending a request:

```
String sendGETApache(HttpGet httpGet) {
    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet); //, httpContext);
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        try {
            entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null) {
                String s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                return s;
            }
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            httpGet.abort();
        } finally {
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            response.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        httpGet.abort();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpGet.releaseConnection();
    }
    return "";
}
```

The HttpClient is an unique object, shared between both threads.
I tried already limiting DefaultMaxPerRoute and MaxTotal to 1 and 2, I even used really big values, no result.
I even implemented an extra thread which calls closeExpiredConnections() and closeIdleConnections() repeatedly, also no improvement.
Do you have any idea what I could do? I think somewhere resources are leaking, but I don't knwo where...
Thank you

Comment: You must close the response-object to return a connection to the pool, nothing more (at least this is the case for apache-httpclient 4.3). Remove all other `abort` and `releaseConnection` calls as well as `closeExpired/IdleConnections` calls. Normally the pool is configured to re-use connections - if it is not (or the server forces a close connection), you'll run out of local ports you can use (65k ports in time_wait, no further connections possible) since you send so many requests in a short time. Turn on debug-logging for the pool to see what is happening with connections in the pool.

Comment: @vanOekel: Thanks, but well, I just tried this, and I get the same problems. I also tried with consuming the entity and without, no effect

Comment: I did some logging: http://pastebin.com/XRDZ9DFL . The "timeout" indicates, where I catch an exception. I can't see whats wrong exactly..

Comment: The log shows no resource leak (all connections are closed) and the cause of the trouble is in "Connect to <server> timed out." which is logged one and half seconds after trying to connect. This prevents connections from being re-used (i.e. each request creates a new connection). I have not seen this kind of error/server behavior before, but I think the logical thing to do is to increase the connect time-out (not to be confused with the connection time-out) from one and a half seconds to 30 seconds.

Comment: Tested this, also no effect. I also tried to play with the values of SocketTimeout, ConnectionRequestTimeout, didn't help. Thats a new log: http://pastebin.com/KkhQjUK2

Comment: Good thing the log shows "wire-logging". The client sends `>> Connection: Keep-Alive` but in the response the server sends `<< Connection: close` which indicates that the server will close the connection after sending the complete response. In other words: there is no way to re-use connections.

Comment: I think I know the problem now: One of the APIs sends a `Connection: close` which prevents the socket from beeing reused. Thats why there are so many waiting connections which... But I don't know if theres a way to solve this. I already tried to do the connection myself via tcp sockets, but it is not possible to reconnect closed sockets